# R list to sparse matrix

Tags: r, mongodb, matrix, sparse-matrix, data-cleaning

I tried to load data from mongodb with R, but I find the query results was unstructured-data, it's a messy list, the results looks like this:

```
 df
[[1]]
list()
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "vector1"
[[2]][[2]]
[1] "vector2"
[[3]]
list()
[[4]]
list()
[[5]]
list()
[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "vector1"
[[6]][[2]]
[1] "vector2"
[[6]][[3]]
[1] "vector3"
```

I tried to convert the list to matrix, just like this:

```
vector1 vector2 vector3
   0       0       0
   1       1       0
   0       0       0
   0       0       0
   0       0       0
   1       1       1
```

I try to use `SparseMatrix()` and `sapply()`, but all failed. And I had to manually create the dataframe above to make the question clear.

Comment: Is there any way you can be (much) more precise? What does the data you are trying to load look like? What commands do you use that throw the messy list? What do you do to perform the list to a matrix? What do you mean you try to use `sapply`? You should consider these questions and revise your question accordingly. That way people can help you - for now there are infinitely many possibilities as to why you get errors: syntax errors, wrong commands, etc. In short: **be specific**.

Comment: Okay, I'll try be more precise next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(df)
#   vector1 vector2 vector3
#1       0       0       0
#2       1       1       0
#3       0       0       0
#4       0       0       0
#5       0       0       0
#6       1       1       1
```

---

Or if we need a `base R` option, we can loop over the `list` elements, convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements in the `list`, get the frequency with `table`, and transpose (`t`) the output.

```
Un1 <- unique(unlist(df))
t(sapply(df, function(x) table(
              if(length(x)==0)
                 factor(x,levels = Un1) 
              else factor(unlist(x), levels=Un1))))
#     vector1 vector2 vector3
#[1,]       0       0       0
#[2,]       1       1       0
#[3,]       0       0       0
#[4,]       0       0       0
#[5,]       0       0       0
#[6,]       1       1       1
```

#### data

```
df <- list(list(),  list("vector1", "vector2"), list(), 
      list(), list(), list("vector1", "vector2", "vector3") )
```

Comment: that's a cool trick, would lapply + rbindlist be faster than transposing for large data?

Comment: @Shape Yes, it could be for large matrices.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I was excluding null cases, but if you'd like a data generator, here you go: `df <- lapply(1:100,function(x) as.list(sample(paste0('vector',1:3),sample(3:0,1))))`

Comment: @Shape Thanks, I was trying to create the OP's example